# Finding inverse of a matrix by adjoint method gives me a negative of the real inverse?

Tags: matrices, inverse

I have a square 3x3 matrix

2 5 5

-1 -1 0

2 4 3

And I found the matrix of cofactors as below

-3 3 -2

5 -4 2

5 -5 3

Then I take the transpose of the matrix of cofactors

-3  5  5

3  -4  -5

-2  3  3

But the result that I see on the book is

3  -5  -5

-3  4  5

2  -2  -3

Could you please tell me what I am missing in this method? Every element of the matrix is negative of what I found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to divide by the determinant of the matrix; it's $-1$.